# invalid local file header signature error in yauzl

Tags: javascript, zip, unzip

I am working on an unzip feature which requires to read zip file from a remote destination, unzip the contents and then create those files over the network to the destination. I am using yauzl with the RandomAccessReader method to read the incoming stream and publish events.

```
const zipQueue = [];

const yauzl = new Yauzl(reader);
const zipfile = yauzl.fromRandomAccessReader(this, this.contentLength, { lazyEntries: true, autoclose: false});
zipfile.on('entry', function(entry){
  zipQueue.push(entry);
  zipfile.readEntry();
  
}).on('end', function() {

  for(const entry of zipQueue) {
   if(/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
    this.emit('directory');
   } else {
     const readStream = zipfile.openReadStream(entry);
     this.emit('file');
   }
 }
})
```

I am getting the zipfile and the entry objects in proper format, but when I try to open the readStream with `zipfile.openReadStream()` it fails `invalid local file header signature: 0x8074b50` after 30 odd entries. I suspect it has something to do with race condition. Is there any other npm package which offers similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting that error because I was piping it from another stream which wasn't done writing, so it was reading an incomplete file.
By listening to the stream 'end' event and only doing it after, it started working.

```
stream.on('end', () => {
    // Unzip here
});
```